# C# How to debug methods called by Invoke()

Tags: c#, debugging, runtime, invoke

I am trying to debug a method in a dynamically created instance of a class:

```
test = (Class1) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
test2 (List<string>)test.GetType().GetMethod("DoSomething").Invoke(test,arguments);
```

I've tried to put in the dynamically invoked method the following:

```
#if DEBUG
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

In "DoSomething" method, but nothing seems to work :(. Debugger is not being called in this dynamically created instance of a class.

P.S. I am compiling the file at runtime (reading class files and then using CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp") and CompilerParameters + CompileAssemblyFromSource). Maybe there are some parameters to activate debugging there? Thanks!!!

Comment: If you don't generate a .pdb to go with the executable file, the debugger has no way to know where to set a breakpoint. `Debugger.Break()` should normally work though, if you have just-in-time debugging set up correctly. Unfortunately, there's not enough context in your question to know what might be not working.

Comment: Thanks! I've figured out how to solve it - compilerParameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true; and then if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Debugger.Break(); in the invoked method.
This works well :).